# Como pegar dados de um input e adicionar a propriedades de uma função Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Estou com muita dúvida pessoal.
Gostaria de pegar dados do meu input e colocá-los dentro de propriedades de uma função.
Se a função conseguisse ser realizada ( captar todos os dados) gostaria de exibir uma mensagem de sucesso, já em caso de erro uma mensagem de erro.
To tentando fazer a função no entanto, não conseigo saber se ela esta pegando corretamente os inputs ou não.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Cadastro de usuário</title>
  </head>
 <body>
<h1> Formulário de Cadastro </h1>
<form name="form">
  <input type="text" name="name" placeholder=" Type your name." maxlength="30"><br><br>
  <input type="number" name="age" placeholder=" Type your age." min="18" maxlength="65"><br><br>
  <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Type your email."><br><br>
  <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Type your password."><br><br>
  <input type="button" name="button" value="Cadastrar" onclick="return validarUser()">
  <script language="javascript" src="./scripts.js"></script>
</form>
```

Código Javascript

```
function validarUser(params){
  var name = form.name.value,
      age = form.age.value,
      email = form.email.value,
      password = form.password.value;
    return true;
    if (validarUser() == true) {
      console.log("Cadastro realizado com sucesso.");
    } else {
      console.log(" Erro ao fazer o cadastro");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece que há algo errado com seu código. Você está dando `return true` sem ao menos fazer nenhuma verificação. Está chamando a função `validarUser` dentro dela mesma, ocasionando um [estouro de pilha](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/La%C3%A7o_infinito). Outro problema é que para chamar a função dentro do onclick é necessário utilizar parênteses `onclick="return validarUser()"`

Tente fazer mais ou menos assim:

```js
function validarUser(){
    
    // você recupera as informações do formulário
    var name = form.name.value,
        age = form.age.value,
        email = form.email.value,
        password = form.password.value;
    
    // verifica cada variável para ver se tem conteúdo ou não
    if (name && age && email && password) {
      console.log("Cadastro realizado com sucesso.");
    } else {
      console.log(" Erro ao fazer o cadastro");
    }
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Cadastro de usuário</title>
  </head>
 <body>
<h1> Formulário de Cadastro </h1>
<form name="form">
  <input type="text" name="name" placeholder=" Type your name." maxlength="30"><br><br>
  <input type="number" name="age" placeholder=" Type your age." min="18" maxlength="65"><br><br>
  <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Type your email."><br><br>
  <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Type your password."><br><br>
  <input type="button" name="button" value="Cadastrar" onclick="return validarUser()">
  <script language="javascript" src="./scripts.js"></script>
</form>
```